# .NET Core Entity Framework - Scaffolding command to only update the model for any delta DB schema changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, scaffolding, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I've currently developed a .NET Core 6 application. Currently, I have generated a DB model within this .NET project using the EF Core Scaffolding command.

After this model was generated, there were a few DB schema changes (creation of new tables, adding new columns to existing tables etc.) implemented. **Now in scenarios where we don't have a track of the exact changes implemented in the DB, how can we construct our Scaffolding command to properly identify and update the existing context model?**

**I'm looking for a way without the need to use -Force option.**

Using the -Force command as follows does overwrite the existing model and also reflect the delta changes, but is there a way to only update the entities which are actually altered at DB-level rather than overwriting every single generated entity?

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=...." -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "C:\App\TestApp\Model\Entities" -Namespace TestApp.Model.Entities -ContextDir "C:\App\TestApp\ContextData" -context TestContextName -ContextNamespace TestApp.ContextData  -Project TestApp.ContextData -Force
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @ErikEJ, To avoid overwriting of entire model. Additionally, using the -Tables also requires providing the exact tables which we intend to add but what if we don't have a track of all such tables?

Comment: Have a look at EF Core power tools and consider the fact that all generated classes are partial